# May one walk alone at night

Tags: travel, evening-night, maseches-pesachim

[Tosfos in Pesachim 2a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=2&format=pdf) discuss why Yosef's brothers were not allowed to go by night. Tosfos say that the reason was because they were not familiar with the territory, and they could have fallen in potholes, but since they were ten they need not have been scared of 'mazikim'. What is the din today? Does a person going alone in his own city which he knows well have to be scared of mazikim? Does this only apply to a talmid chochom, perhaps? Or maybe mazikim don't exist today?

Comment: questions on present daf yomi

Comment: see rmo yore daio 116:5. Rav shulchan aruch. Turai oven chagigah 3b.

Comment: Or maybe mazikin never existed...